# CakePHP3 Call to a member function primaryKey() on null

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.0, hybridauth

I'm using hybrid-auth plugin of cakePhp3. And getting such a response after login :

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: UsersTable [ROOT/vendor/admad/cakephp-hybridauth/src/Auth/HybridAuthAuthenticate.php, line 289]

Fatal Error
Cake\Error\FatalErrorException

Error: Call to a member function primaryKey() on null File /home/user10/public_html/app/vendor/admad/cakephp-hybridauth/src/Auth/HybridAuthAuthenticate.php Line: 289
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: In pulgin it is clear that you have a `users table` with at least `email field`. after that you have to run `bin/cake migrations migrate -p ADmad/HybridAuth
` command as said in https://github.com/ADmad/CakePHP-HybridAuth#database

Comment: The "_Undefined variable_" notice indicates a possible bug in the plugin. You may want to report that.